# Add class to following buttons inside a map function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, classname

I have a function that adds class onClick.

```
import * as React from 'react'

class ThisClass extends React.Component<any,any> {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {active: ''}
    this.ThisFunction = this.ThisFunction.bind(this)
  }

  const items = ['button1', 'button2', 'button3']

  ThisFunction (i) {
    this.setState({
      active: i
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {
          items.map((item, i) => {
            return(
              <button
                onClick={()=>this.ThisFunction(i)}>{item}
                className={`this_button ${this.state.active ? 'active' : ''}`}
                {item}
              </button>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ThisClass
```

What's suppose to happen:

```
<div>
 <button class='this_button active'>button1</button>
 <button class='this_button active'>button2</button>
 <button class='this_button'>button3</button>
</div>
```

What's really happening:

```
<div>
 <button class='this_button active'>button1</button>
 <button class='this_button'>button2</button>
 <button class='this_button'>button3</button>
</div>
```

I need to have a maximum of two active' class onClick function. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: You want to have multiple active buttons?
Or just one active button at any given time?

Comment: A multiple active button but one at a time. Say, if I click the first button, it'll be active. Then if I click another button, first button will remain active, so as the newly clicked button. But only a maximum of two.

Comment: What happens if two buttons are active and I click third button?
Which of the two will go to inactive?

Comment: The first two buttons remain active, others should be disabled.

Comment: Posted an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Change your state to hold an array of active indices and change the handler to only maintain the last two set (i.e. kick out the least recently used)

```
state = {
  active: []
};

thisFunction = i => {
  if (this.state.active.includes(i)) return; // already active!!
  const active = [...this.state.active, i].slice(-2); // keep last 2
  this.setState({ active });
};
```

You also had some syntax errors in the button rendering. The classname was being set as part of the button text. Set the active class if `this.state.active` array includes the active index

```
{["button1", "button2", "button3"].map((item, i) => {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => this.thisFunction(i)}
      className={`this_button ${
        this.state.active.includes(i) ? "active" : ""
      }`}
    >
      {item}
    </button>
  );
})}
```

[image: Edit confident-platform-72759]

Comment: How do you get this embedded edit on codesandbox?
Is it part of paid plan on codesandbox?

Comment: @UtsavPatel Not that I'm aware of. Click "share" in upper right > "embed", then in the modal in the right panel are the share options, "Share CodeSandbox Button" is second accordion, copy/past the markdown.

Comment: @DrewReese, your code works in the sandbox but some, doesn't have effect on mine. Stil figuring it out how.

Comment: @DaveMoreno What aspect are you referring to? I can try point you in the right direction.

Comment: @DrewReese Clicking the buttons or the function didn't produce the class 'active'. Also, in your code, you can click the buttons more than 3 hits. The condition should satisfy only 2 hits. After that, all the remaining buttons should be disabled (assuming I have more than 3 buttons).

Comment: @DaveMoreno I copy/pasted your code initially. I had to add a CSS rule for the active class, `.active`, I just picked a lightgreen background (it's `styles.css` in my sandbox). Is this what you're missing or is the *actual* active class not getting set on the element? (this can be checked if you inspect the DOM in the browser window)

Comment: @DrewReese. The actual 'active' class is not showing in the DOM

Comment: @DrewReese BTW, I'm using react 15.

Comment: @DaveMoreno Ew, I'm sorry. What specific versions of `react`, `react-dom`, and `react-scripts` are you using? I dropped down to v15.6.2 and the sandbox page doesn't even load.

Comment: @DrewReese it's 15.4.1. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @DaveMoreno Ok, working sandbox in react 15.4.1, same link. I see the active class being toggled.

Comment: @DaveMoreno add this in the sandbox provided by Drew reese.
`if (this.state.active.length === 2) return; ` on line number 10. 

This will not reset the previously selected buttons as you wanted.

Comment: @UtsavPatel Possible older browser as well then

Comment: @DrewReese Actually if you read the comments on OP, he has mentioned the behaviour as first two buttons always. That is not clear from the question itself.
Your implementation gives the last two buttons.
I am using FireFox nightly 77.0a1

Comment: @DrewReese sorry mate. Really not showing 'active' in my DOM. But works in your sandbox. I even restructured your codes. still not showing 'active' in mine

Comment: @DaveMoreno No worries, browser support and old versions of react can likely be finicky like this. Without being able to reproduce your environment there is unfortunately not much I can do.

Answer (score -1):

There are some major errors in your code.

1. You are putting the className property as a child on the button, is an attribute instead
2. Every child on a list e.g your buttons needs to have a [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)
3. You are binding twice the function, one on the constructor and another one on the onClick event using an arrow function. [Bind a function](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance)

```js
class ThisClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {active: ''}
  }

  
  ThisFunction (i) {
    this.setState({
      active: i
    })
  }

  render(){

    const items = ['button1', 'button2', 'button3']

    return(
      <div>
        {
          items.map((item, i) => {
            return(
              <button
                key={i}
                onClick={() => this.ThisFunction(i)}
                className={`this_button ${this.state.active === i ? 'active' : ''}`}>
                  {item}
              </button>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ThisClass />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```